# Alternative music player

Tags: jquery, html5-audio, audio-player, flashplayer-10

Is there any player that does not require flash to play the sound?

I have already tried html5 player but it is also not working. I am currently working on a small project in Raspberry Pie. Due to low hardware specification, it cannot load flash integrated player to play the music?

Is there any alternative to this?

I need really basic music player. Or even a background music would do the trick. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other widely available frameworks that have audio capability that I know of are silverlight and unity, but I doubt those are supported on Raspberry Pie and are probably just as heavy as flash.

I think your best course of action is to research why HTML5 audio might not be working, or build a native application.

Usually web applications like Pandora instead offer a native application on the mobile device instead of trying to get the website to work, since they would have the same challenges you do for getting a website to play audio.